# how to get array of filesnames present in sub-directories using perl ( without using File::Find)

Tags: perl

I'm trying to get the names of files present in sub-directories. Further I want to get the size of array and search the text in individual files

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

$dir = $ARGV[0];
my @filesList;
opendir(DIR, $dir) || die "Unable to open the directory";
@contents=readdir(DIR);
foreach $listitem ( @contents )
{
    if ( -d $listitem )
    {
        opendir(DIR,$listitem);
        @c1=readdir(DIR);
        foreach  $firstlevel(@c1)  # first level directory structure
        {
            if (-d $firstlevel) {
                opendir(DIR,$firstlevel);
                @c2=readdir(DIR);
                foreach  $secondlevel(@c2) {  #second level directory structure
                    push(@filesList, $secondlevel);
                }
            } else {
                 # push(@filesList, $firstlevel);
            }
        }
        #push(@filesList, $listitem);   
    } else {
        push(@filesList, $listitem);
    }
}
$size = @filesList;
print "array size : $size";
foreach $file(@filesList)
{
    print "$file"; 
}
close(DIR);
```

All this I want to work without using `Find::Find`, I'm getting error for `use File::Find`

Also, how can I get the size of an array

Comment: What's the error you receive when you use `Find:find`? Also, avoid asking multiple questions at once, otherwise the question may be considered as *too broad*

Comment: it gives error as can't locate Find.pm file. BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at line**
but the .pm file is present at installation location.

Comment: so, it is telling you module not found... you have the module installed?

Comment: What is the exact `use` line? Is it `use File::find` or is it `use File::Find`? You should really use  `File::Find` because it is there and does what you need.

Comment: Possible typo `Find::Find` instead of `File::Find`?

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53408544/edit) to copy and paste the **exact** error message you get when trying to use File::Find. File::Find has been included in the standard Perl distribution since 1994. It seems very unlikely that a properly-installed Perl would not have it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`scalar` is what you need to get an array's size, although you can omit scalar and still get the number of elements as it seems you already have.  You have to clarify what exactly you mean by "array size" if not this.  The cleaner way is to use File::Find, but if you just want something quick, you can do a system call to find, or any other system command, using backticks:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @files = `find $ARGV[0] -type f`;
my $size = scalar(@files);
print "Number of files = $size\n";
foreach my $file(@files) {
    print "$file";
}
```